# Streaming videos from a Ubuntu to Chromecast

Tags: ubuntu, video, streaming, chromecast

I have a MiniDLNA 1.1.4 setup on an ubuntu 14.04. I also have a Chromecast. I would like to be able to stream a video on my local server to the Chromecast like I do with Netflix. I have downloaded a couple of apps, but the free ones didn't work, video was pausing and resuming or stopping, and I didn't want to pay for an app that I wasn't sure if it was going to work. I would like it to do with a phone or a tablet. Is this possible or are we in an early stage? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Plex.  Among other things, Plex lets you stream local content to a Chromecast and runs really well on Ubuntu.  Plex is free for the functionality you listed, they do have a paid version but for simple local streaming it would not be necessary.

[Plex.tv](http://plex.tv)

Comment: I am using Plex at home and is working, thank you for your answer.